# Ms Access Rank and match two querys

Tags: sql, ms-access, match, rank

I've been stuck with this problems for a while, and couldn't get it right yet. Here it is:

I have some tables in my Acces database and some querys. I have a query to select some fields and order by, say, their frequency. This is done for two tables, giving me two ranks. Looks like this (and are sorted DESC, so the higher Frequency is on top):

```
Table 1                    Table 2
Value1   Frequency1         Value2 Frequency2
```

Table2.Value2 is a subset of Table1.Value1, so I want to match Value2 and Value1 plus Add a Column showing Value2 position (rank) on Table2, so I can compare it's position on Table1 and Table2 ranks.So I'll have something like:

```
Table3
Value1 Frequency1 Frequency2 PositionTable2
```

I've searched how to return the line number of a field (couldn't get it to work), and I can put the two tables together and match by Value, but can't get the result I need.

My knowledge of SQL is limited, and I don't understand VB at all, so please be nice :)
Thanks in advance

**Edit**
Example:

```
Table 1                    Table 2
Name    Frequency    Name    Frequency
Mary       5         Paul     2
John       4         John     1
Paul       3
```

Output I want:

```
Table 3               
Name    Frequency    Frequency2    RankIn2
Mary       5                                  //doesn't appear in table2, freq=null rankin2=null
John       4            1            2            //second line of table2
Paul       3            2            1            //first line in table2
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the two tables along with what you want as a result.

Comment: What determines the rank in Table 3?

Comment: You are not showing a Rank in Table1.  You have a frequency in desc order.  Do you want the RankIn2 to autoincrement based on that value?

Comment: Well, there's no rank explicitely, but the descending order creates one. I think it'll have to be something like finding out the line number of Name in Table2 to put in the column.I'm gonna edit the example, maybe it'll be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do this in two steps:

Step 1 -- Create a query (say, named "Table 2 with Rank") that calculates the rank for Table 2.  The SQL might look something like this:

```
SELECT
    [Table 2].[Name],
    [Table 2].[Frequency],
    Count(*) AS [Rank]
FROM
    [Table 2],
    [Table 2] AS [Self]
WHERE
    [Self].[Frequency]>=[Table 2].[Frequency]
GROUP BY
    [Table 2].[Name],
    [Table 2].[Frequency];
```

If there are "ties" in Table 2 (that is, different names with the same frequency), this query will assign the same rank to both.  If you don't want this, change the WHERE clause to specify how you want to break ties.  For example, in the event of a tie, the WHERE clause...

```
WHERE
    [Self].[Frequency]>[Table 2].[Frequency]
    OR
    ([Self].[Frequency]=[Table 2].[Frequency] AND [Self].[Name]<=[Table 2].[Name])
```

...will assign the lower numbered rank to the name that comes first the in the alphabet.

Step 2 -- Create another query that joins the first query to Table 1.  The SQL might look something like this:

```
SELECT
    [Table 1].[Name], 
    [Table 1].[Frequency], 
    [Table 2 with Rank].[Frequency] AS [Frequency2], 
    [Table 2 with Rank].Rank AS [RankIn2]
FROM 
    [Table 1] LEFT JOIN [Table 2 with Rank] 
        ON [Table 1].[Name] = [Table 2 with Rank].[Name]
ORDER BY
    [Table 1].[Frequency] DESC;
```

Comment: Step1 gave me a rank where tha positions of some rows is the same (same rank) even though I used the OR clause you sugested, and the rank misses numbers, because os repetitions (1,2,4,4,6,6...). Would the OR clause work if the names had spaces?

Comment: Sorry.  If you use the OR, you need to change the first condition to use a strictly greater than comparison, as in `[Self].[Frequency]>[Table 2].[Frequency]`. I've edited my answer to show this.

Answer (score 1):

I would use VBA because Access' limited SQL doesn't understand the rank concept very well. Here are the steps.

1. Create a 3rd field for Table2 and call it Rank.
2. Create the following subroutine by pressing Alt+F11, Insert->Module and pasting the following code in the editor window that opens.

   Public Sub RankTable()

   ```
   Dim rs As Recordset, iRank As Integer, strQuery As String

   strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Table2 ORDER BY Freq DESC"

   Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQuery, dbOpenDynaset)

   rs.MoveFirst
   iRank = 1

   Do

       rs.Edit
       rs.Fields(3) = iRank
       rs.Update

       rs.MoveNext
       iRank = iRank + 1

   Loop While Not rs.EOF

   rs.Close
   ```

   End Sub
3. Run the above subroutine. (Remember you have to run this every time there is an update to Table2.)
4. Create the query

   SELECT Table1.Name, Table1.Frequency, Table2.Frequency AS Frequency2, Table2.Rank
   FROM Table1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Name ON Table1.Name = Table2.Name
   ORDER BY Table2.Frequency

Comment: My code's not formatting correctly, no idea why. Sorry about that.

Comment: As I said, I don't understand VB at all. Should I leave the lines "Sub RankTable" and "EndSub" out?

Comment: Also, Table1 and Table2 are querys. Can I insert a new column called Rank in the result of the query? And can I run this routine in a query?

Comment: You do need the lines Sub RankTable and EndSub. My code's not formatting correctly, so I can see why you would think that.

Comment: This will not work if Table2 is a query. However, that can easily be resolved. Turn your query Table2 into a Make Table query and run it. Be sure to modify the subroutine to include the new table name in the query string. Be sure also to run the Table2 query to re-make your table every time any of the underlying data changes.

Comment: Can you tell me how to run the subroutine from Rank from table design?

Comment: You click into the subroutine and press F5.