# MS Access Rank GPA With Grouping

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, rank

I've gotten close to finding an answer to a grouped ranking but not quite. I have 2 tables

Org Table

```
Chapter Council
DDD     IFC
DT      IFC
GG      IFC
AA      MGC
BB      MGC
CC      MGC
DD      IND
EE      IND
```

PSRoster

```
Chapter GRDPoints  TakeGPA  MemberName  Status
DDD    2.0           2         Bill     Active
DT     3.2           3         Jim      New Member
GG     4.0           6         Sue      New Member
AA     2.3           6         Jill     Active
BB     1.3           5         Joe      New Member
CC     3.2           5         Frank    Active
DD     3.2           4         Leslie   Active
EE     4.0           3         Sandra   Active
```

I have to calculate GPA for each Chapter on the fly and then rank them and group them by Council. I have no problem calculating the GPA then doing sub queries to get other values, but I can't seem to get the ranking to work. Below is my SQL. What am I missing to get the GPA ranked by Council?

```
SELECT 
    Org.Council, 
    Org.Chapter, 
    Round((Sum(PSRoster.GrdPoints)/Sum(PSRoster.TakeGPA)),3) AS [Chapter Average],
    ( 
        Select Round((Sum(PSRoster.GrdPoints)/Sum(PSRoster.TakeGPA)),3) AS [Chapter Average] 
        FROM Org INNER JOIN PSRoster ON Org.Chapter = PSRoster.Chapter 
        WHERE PSRoster.Status = 'Active'  
    ) AS [Active Avg GPA],
    ( 
        Select Round((Sum(PSRoster.GrdPoints)/Sum(PSRoster.TakeGPA)),3) AS [Chapter Average] 
        FROM Org 
        INNER JOIN PSRoster ON Org.Chapter = PSRoster.Chapter 
        WHERE PSRoster.Status = 'New Member'  
    ) AS [New Member Avg GPA],
    (
        SELECT COUNT(PSRoster.Semester) AS [Total Number of 4] 
        FROM PSRoster 
        WHERE (PSRoster.Semester = 4.00  ) And Org.Chapter = PSRoster.Chapter 
    ) AS [FourOs]
FROM Org INNER JOIN PSRoster ON Org.Chapter = PSRoster.Chapter
Group By Org.Council, Org.Chapter;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463116/use-access-sql-to-do-a-grouped-ranking

Comment: I can't do a count in an aggregate function.