# MS Access: Order by calculated field (using alias)

Tags: sql, ms-access

In a select query I calculate a field using a nested select. I would like to order the results by the calculated field (rank), however Access does not recognize the field rank. (When I run the query, Access asks for the parameter value of rank.)

```
SELECT
  *,
  (select count(*)
   from tbl as tbl2
   where tbl.customers > tbl2.customers and tbl.dept = tbl2.dept
  ) + 1 as rank
FROM tbl
ORDER BY rank
```

[The example query is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463116/use-access-sql-to-do-a-grouped-ranking) post]

Comment: Can you do the sub-query first, then `, *`, then `ORDER BY 1`?

Comment: I tried rearranging and `ORDER BY 1`, but that does not have any effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a Derived table

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT
  *,
  (select count(*)
   from tbl as tbl2
   where tbl.customers > tbl2.customers and tbl.dept = tbl2.dept
  ) + 1 as rank
FROM tbl
) as newtbl
ORDER BY rank
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you'd have to:

```
order by ((select count(*) from tbl as tbl2 where
tbl.customers > tbl2.customers and tbl.dept = tbl2.dept) + 1)
```

Comment: I tried using the select statement for the `ORDER BY` (adding the missing opening bracket), however I get a syntax error. Not sure where that comes from.

Answer (score 0):

(STEP 1) Start writing an Access query that you will call QUERY1, containing the calculated field as an alias

(STEP 2) write a second query QUERY2 which references QUERY1 with the clause ORDER BY that contains the alias name you created in QUERY1

(STEP 3) test it and if it works as desired:

(STEP 4) modify QUERY2 by substituting the clause "SELECT FROM QUERY1" by the clause "SELECT FROM (XXXXX)"  where XXXXX will contain all the sql statements used to define QUERY1, inserted inside the two round parenthesis. After the right parenthesis you can keep the ORDER BY statement refered to the alias fields.

That should work. 
Generally speaking, this technique of breaking the sql statements into Access queries that are subsequently referenced as tables and then replaced by their contained sql code, have solved many issues with complicated nested queries.

example:

Quer1 ="
SELECT Tabella1.Descriz as description, Tabella1.V1, Tabella1.V2, Tabella1.V3, Sqr((Tabella1.[V1]-0.1)^2+(Tabella1.[V2]-0.7)^2+(Tabella1.[V3]-0.2)^2) AS distance
FROM Tabella1 "

Quer2 (initial version)
= "SELECT description, V1, V2, V3, distance
FROM (
Quer1 ) ORDER BY  distance ;"

Quer2 (modified version after check) =
"SELECT description, V1, V2, V3, distance
FROM (SELECT Tabella1.Descriz as description, Tabella1.V1, Tabella1.V2, Tabella1.V3, Sqr((Tabella1.[V1]-0.1)^2+(Tabella1.[V2]-0.7)^2+(Tabella1.[V3]-0.2)^2) AS distance
FROM Tabella1 ) 
ORDER BY  distance ;"