# SQL RANK() equivalent for VBA ADODB.Recordset

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

I'm trying to write an SQL query in VBA for an ADODB.Recordset object that generates a calculated rank field. Using transact-SQL does not work as seen in the sample here.

```
strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT [MONTH-YYYY], Location, (SUM([O/T Earnings])/SUM([Monthly Earnings])) AS OT_AS_PCT "
strSQL = strSQL & "RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [MONTH-YYYY] ORDER BY (SUM([O/T Earnings])/SUM([Monthly Earnings])) DESC) AS RANK "
strSQL = strSQL & "FROM [Overtime Data$] "
strSQL = strSQL & "GROUP BY [MONTH-YYYY], Location "

rst_ranks.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

I've noticed when using functions in ADODB before that SQL functions do not work and VBA functions must be used in their place. Is there a VBA Rank() function that allows the PARTITION BY parameter.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem isn't the ADODB Recordset. It's the data engine you're talking to. A Recordset is happy to show you these results, if the database you're reading from supports it. You could use this exact code just fine with a connection to Sql Server instead of Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strangely, standard SQL functions such as RANK() or BETWEEN() do not work in VBA/ADODB record strings.  Instead, use of existing VBA functions are necessary and work the same.

Answer (score 0):

What's your ADODB Connection provider ?

If you're trying to use Rank() against an Access database it wont work.

Go and see this question [Grouped Ranking in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463116/use-access-sql-to-do-a-grouped-ranking) to see how to do rank with access