# How to efficiently rank a very long column in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

Suppose I have a very large (= many rows) excel spreadsheet, and I want to put in (say) column `B` the rank of element in column `A`. Now, of course, I can just enter the formula `RANK(Ai, A2:AGAZILLION)`, but this will be quadratic time, which is bad for large  values of gazillion. Alternately, I can introduce an auxillary column `C`, where `Ci = i,` then sort on `A`, then set `Bi=i`, then sort on `C`, then remove `C`, which is reasonably efficient, but does not seem like the most elegant way. Any thoughts?

Comment: A modern Excel worksheet only has (say) 1,048,576  rows, which is substantially less than (say) a gazillion.

Comment: @Jeeped you must have a different definition of gazillion than I. In any case, perhaps you agree that 1048576^2 IS at least a gazillion.

Comment: I am also curious why this would be downvoted.

Comment: I would have thought using ADO and the RANK() function from SQL would have been a good solution but ADO doesn't support RANK() when reading from Excel worksheets - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614674/sql-rank-equivalent-for-vba-adodb-recordset)

Answer (score 1):

one way is to enter the Rank formula as a multi-cell array formula:
select B2:Bgazillion
enter =Rank(a2:agazillion,a2:agazillion) and press control shift enter

But sadly this is not fast: although it should do the internal sort only once it is not coded that way.

Comment: Ah, thanks! The msft documentation does not seem to mention this possibility (and without trying it, which I will right now, it is not clear that this is faster than the dumb way.

Comment: But here is the second dumb question: how do you actually select B2:Bgazillion quickly (without scrolling for ten minutes) (in my case, gazillion is about 180000)

Comment: Assuming that column B is empty: click on cell Bgazillion; hold <Ctrl> and <Shift> then press the Up arrow (selects B1:Bgazillion); now hold <Shift> then press the Down arrow (selects B2:Bgazillion)

Comment: @barrowc truly you are wise in the ways of science!

Comment: Well, the good news is that @barrowc's suggestions are spot on, the bad news is that the rank computation has hung (and I don't know if it is even computing, since excel is not claiming to be coming anything). Sigh.

Comment: Sorry Igor: I should have checked that the array version was sensibly coded: but its not!