# How to Rank Based on Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to score people in Microsoft Access based on the count they have for a particular category.

There are 7 possible categories a person can have against them, and I want to assigned each person a score from 1-7, with 1 being assigned to the highest scoring category, 7 being the lowest. They might not have an answer for every category, in which case that category can be ignored.

The aim would be to have an output result as shown in this image:

[image]

I've tried a few different things, including partition over and joins, but none have worked. To be honest I think I'm way off the mark with the queries I've been trying. I've tried to write the code in SQL from scratch, and used query builder.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Access SQL to do a grouped ranking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463116/use-access-sql-to-do-a-grouped-ranking)

Answer (score 0):

As you for an email can have *duplicated counts*, you will need *two subqueries* for this:

```sql
SELECT 
    Score.email, 
    Score.category, 
    Score.[Count], 
        (Select Count(*) From Score As T Where 
            T.email = Score.email And 
            T.[Count] >= Score.[Count])-
        (Select Count(*) From Score As S Where 
            S.email = Score.email And 
            S.[Count] = Score.[Count] And 
            S.category > Score.category) AS Rank
FROM 
    Score
ORDER BY 
    Score.email, 
    Score.[Count] DESC, 
    Score.category;
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

For categories with **equal** `Count` values for the **same** `email`, the following will rank the records alphabetically descending by `Category` name (since this is what is shown in your example):

```sql
select t.email, t.category, t.count,
(
    select count(*) from YourTable u
    where t.email = u.email and 
    ((t.count = u.count and t.category <= u.category) or t.count < u.count)
) as rank
from YourTable t
order by t.email, t.count desc, t.category desc
```

Change both references of `YourTable` to the name of your table.