# How to calculate student rank in access

Tags: ms-access, rank, calculation

I want to calculate student rank based on their obtmarks as per below tables. Suppose any student scored highest marks in their class but he/she fail in any one subjects then they shouldn't consider for rank.

**1. Table name is "resultdata"**

Total marks of full marks is(1000)

pass marks is 33

```
ID  |   subject ID   | subject        | fullmarks | obtmarks |passmarks
1   | 1              |  HINDI         |   100     |  80      | 33
2   | 2              |  ENGLISH       |   100     |  90      | 33
3   | 3              |  MATHEMATICS   |   100     |  76      | 33
4   | 4              |  SOCIAL SCIENCE|   100     |  69      | 33
```

like that others subjects also.

**2. Table name is "result"**

```
 ID|result    | student |student|mother |father |class|term/    |rollno|section|
   |date      | ID      |name   |name   |name   |     |semester |      |       |
1  |11.09.2019|   1     |Jasmine|Eliana |Ritesh |  8  |1st Term |  10  |   A   | 
2  |11.09.2019|   2     |Kiyas  |Fanny  |Rajnish|  10 |1st Term |  1   |   B   |
3  |11.09.2019|   3     |Ena    |Rashmi |Prakash|  9  |1st Term |  12  |   C   |
4  |11.09.2019|   4     |Sunaina|Ankita |Chander|  7  |1st Term |  15  |   A   |
5  |11.09.2019|   5     |Ankit  |Sujata |Roy    |  8  |1st Term |  11  |   B   |
6  |11.09.2019|   6     |Krishna|Bala   |Gopal  |  8  |1st Term |  5   |   C   |
7  |11.09.2019|   7     |Ranga  |Hima   |Hitesh |  9  |1st Term |  7   |   A   |
8  |11.09.2019|   8     |Suraj  |Priya  |Hemal  |  7  |1st Term |  10  |   B   |
9  |11.09.2019|   9     |Saurabh|Archana|Suyog  |  10 |1st Term |  9   |   B   |
```

**3. Table name is "subjects"**

```
 ID  | subject        | fullmarks |  passmarks
 1   |  HINDI         |  100      |  33
 2   |  ENGLISH       |  100      |  33
 3   | MATHEMATICS    |  100      |  33
 4   | SOCIAL SCIENCE |  100      |  33
 5   | Computer       |   50      |  20
```

like that others subjects also.

ID of subjects table and subjectID of resultdata table has relationship.

How to resolve this issue using a formula or vba code?

- Condition1: Calculate every student rank on basis of their total obtained marks. But any student has failed in any subjects they will not consider for TOP 10 rank.
- Condition 2: Calculate every student rank on basis of their total obtained marks.

I tried this formula in query but it does not work:

```
Rank: DCount("*","resultdata","[fullmarks]>" & [obtmarks])+1
```

Comment: What language are you using? is this r? SQL? You should edit your question to provide additional clarification and tags.

Comment: Clearly mentioned in questions. By the way I am using ms office >>access 2019

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Access SQL to do a grouped ranking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463116/use-access-sql-to-do-a-grouped-ranking)

Comment: It's not working for me. I have another condition on it i.e. if student fails in any subject they will not get any Rank however he/she scored highest marks in the class.

Comment: @June7 thanks for your suggestions but it not work for me. Because my condition is different and that query doesn't resolve my problem.

Comment: Sample data table should include StudentID and multiple student records.

Comment: Cannot rank students with this data because there is no relationship between students and obtained marks. No way of knowing which marks belong to which students. Where is table showing grades each student earned for each subject?

Comment: Suppose I'll create a field for grade through query in resultdata after that it is possible? If Yes, then you can assume a Grade field in resultdata table and try to resolve. If necessary then create Rank field in the same table or result table.

Comment: Sorry, that does not make sense. resultdata already has grade field, just not which students got those grades.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion where to change or add any new field in any of these table to calculate rank?

Comment: You need a table that has each student/subject/grade. I am not seeing that in the sample data provided nor any way to modify to produce. Why would you call table 'result' when there aren't any results - it's just general student info, no grade results. What is significance of 'result date'?

Comment: I have created a **Create Result Form** where under result table I am using **resultdata table as subfrm.** Now their effect is that when I open that **Create Result Form** for make result, student data has been captured and from their I have only select subject and put their obtained marks according to obtained marks %age, Grade, Remarks are updated. **These 3 fields (%age, Grade, Remarks) auto updated through query which runs behind that.** like that it works. **Result Date is only for info on which date result will publish.** I hope now you will get the solution. No option for attachment.

Comment: @june, did you get any idea?

Comment: Forms are not relevant. If you have a dataset (table or query) with StudentID and Grade and Passmarks (which you have not yet shown), comments in answer apply, nothing new to offer.

Comment: @june, is it possible to create a text box in the form and write the formula and get the rank?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I have already provided all the info I can on ranking records.

Comment: @june i tried your query as you suggest but it doesn't work. can you elaborate.

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? I built tables as you describe then queries work for me. Need to edit question with your attempted queries.

Comment: @june run the both query it showing only these field name nothing no rank. fields name are *sumofobtmarks, studentID, Rank* from query2 from query passing fields name *studentID, sumofobtmarks*

Comment: @june I run the both query but rank will not displayed on report or anywhere. Can you share your mail id so I'll send you my database.

Comment: I don't share email. If you want to provide files then I suggest you use a forum where uploading files is accepted and encouraged.

Comment: @june in which forum, can you suggest anyone.

Comment: There are many. AccessForums.net, access-programmers.co.uk, UtterAccess. Google for more.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to include students with any failing grade then do a preliminary query to eliminate them. Then use that query to rank the remaining students. Consider:

Query1: Passing

```
SELECT resultdata.StudentID, Sum(resultdata.obtmarks) AS SumOfobtmarks
FROM resultdata
GROUP BY resultdata.StudentID
HAVING resultdata.StudentID Not In (SELECT resultdata.StudentID
       FROM resultdata
       WHERE resultdata.obtmarks<[passmarks]);
```

Query2:

```
SELECT Passing.SumOfobtmarks, Passing.StudentID, 
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM Passing AS T1 WHERE T1.SumOfobtmarks > Passing.SumOfobtmarks)+1 AS Rank
FROM Passing
ORDER BY Passing.SumOfobtmarks DESC;
```

However, if multiple students have same score, results will likely not be satisfactory. This is a common topic with many examples. For one review http://allenbrowne.com/ranking.html. Best solution might be one involving a 'temp' table as explained in Allen's article. Or try Lebans Serialize function, link is in Allen's article. Another excellent tutorial demonstrating these techniques http://www.mendipdatasystems.co.uk/rank-order-queries/4594424063.

Comment: @ June, In query 2 you mentioned T1, can you tell me is it define as variable? Also let me know where these query can we write in SQL view in access or in query design view. I am new in access.

Comment: please brief about query 2 like passing, T1

Comment: T1 is alias name for query Passing so Passing can be used twice in same SELECT statement. Can copy/paste these query statements into SQL view of query builder.

Comment: above query can finding 1 to 10 rank or it calculate all student's rank? If it calculate all student's rank then again it will not resolve my problem I need Rank 1 to 10 only without fail in any subjects.

Comment: That requirement is not stated in your question. Try `SELECT TOP 10` in second query.

Comment: Yes I agree that I forget to write. But that is final I want. But where to add in second query these SELECT TOP 10 and how can you explain.

Comment: All you do is add `TOP 10` after `SELECT` of outer query. See other info added to answer.

Comment: Can you explain, you mentioned in that statement StudentID. When I doesn't make any such type of field in my resultdata table. how it will calculate? Result data table I am using only for keeping the record subject wise. How it is possible to calculate rank?

Comment: How can you have student grades without a StudentID? How do you expect to rank students without StudentID? It needs to be somewhere. I have asked you to provide a more complete sample of source data. Regardless, example and comments in my answer are still conceptually pertinent.

Comment: wait. I have another table which name is result. There structure is like that. Use | for separate.         
 Field name | data type           | description                                            
 ID                 |  Auto number   | primary key  student ID| number| mother's name|short text father's name|short text fullmarks| number obtmarks| number pass marks| number

Comment: Edit your question to show info. Build Query1 so that it includes necessary tables to retrieve related data.

Comment: I didn't get you.

Comment: What do you not understand about building query that joins tables to retrieve related data? If resultdata does not have StudentID, how do you expect to rank students and relate this dataset to the Students table? Have already provided enough resources for you to resolve this.

Comment: Leave that. I'll manage own. Which information you want I already mentioned in previous comment. Where I mentioned about my result table.

Comment: You should edit question with additional info. Comment is hard to read table structure and anyone reading question will not see without having to go through comments. If you are now saying there is StudentID in resultdata, then explain why my suggestion is not working for you. I already pointed out issue and alternatives.

Comment: still you aren't able to understand. I have 2 tables result and resultdata. In which result table stored student personal information and resultdata has  marks obtain, grade and remarks data stored. More than that I have last table which name is subject and here only I stored all subjects name and their full and pass marks. That's it. I never mentioned StudentID in resultdata table. Now you assume I mentioned, I can't do anything. If still you have any problem to understand my question. Kindly ignore it. I'll manage my own it will take time to resolve but it will resolve.

Comment: As I said, edit question to clarify data structure as well as provide sample raw data. Your comment showed fields: StudentID, fullmarks, obtmarks, passmarks in a table named result. Why would I not think data has StudentID associated with grade info? Build query that joins tables to retrieve all info needed for ranking. I understand you want to rank records. You have not provided data to work with.

Comment: No one has to stop anyone to what they assume and what they think. Tomorrow morning I'll provide the sample data what you want right now it's late night as per IST.

Comment: Question edited. Sample data and table name provided.

Comment: @juneI paste above query in query design mode at sql view. But it gives error **Characters found after end SQL statement.**

Comment: I added student ID and class name in the result data table. Afterwards above comment error showing.

Comment: Posted queries worked for me. I can't see what you did so can't explain error. But make sure you pasted over the `SELECT;` that is in new query by default.

Comment: Means you are saying after SELECT semicolon will use

Comment: Don't understand that statement. I meant a new query in SQLView already has `SELECT;` displayed. Must remove that if you copy/paste an SQL statement.

Comment: It means I'll remove **SELECT** in both query or from SQL view window I'll remove **SELECT**

Comment: It means what I said. When you open a new query in SQLView, it shows simply just `SELECT;`. Remove that.

Comment: I removed `SELECT;` from a new query in sql view but still it showing same error i.e.**Characters found after end SQL statement** Doesn't find the attachment option otherwise definitely i attached the screenshot.