# Add a number based on customer and date of purchase

Tags: ms-access

I have a list of customer email addresses and dates of their orders. I need to provide a sequential number to each customer's order.

I can perform this task in Excel by using a countifs function. However, my data is getting too large to handle there and I'd prefer to set this up in access.

The data comes in all out of order, so first I order by Customer Email and then a second order by Date of Purchase. From there, I want to apply a sequential number to their order based on date. So if joe has three orders, I want to know which order was first, second, and third.

[image: rank outcome example]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Access SQL to do a grouped ranking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463116/use-access-sql-to-do-a-grouped-ranking) also review http://allenbrowne.com/ranking.html

Comment: I referred to that original post; the problem, though, is that I need the rank to be sequenced based on the date. When I attempted the solution, it returned a result of "1" in each row and did not sequence.

Comment: You should edit question to show attempted SQL. I expect the nested query is not correct. Simplest would be to do this in report design.

Comment: Doesn't ordering by date tell readers which is 1st, 2nd, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Following guidance by Allen Browne http://allenbrowne.com/ranking.html, consider:

```
SELECT Table1.*, 
     (SELECT Count(*) AS Rank FROM Table1 AS Dupe 
      WHERE Dupe.[Date of Purchase]<Table1.[Date of Purchase] 
      AND Dupe.[Customer Email] = Table1.[Customer Email])+1 AS Rank
FROM Table1
ORDER BY [Customer Email], [Date of Purchase];
```