# How to create (multiple) Ranks in 1 Query by cluster?

Tags: sql, ms-access, rank

[enter image description here][1]

I have a query with different "clusters" of products, sold in different countries.

- Cluster 1: Computer-Keyboard-Mouse
- Cluster 2: PlayStation-Xbox-Nintendo
- Cluster 3: Macbook-Lenovo-hp

Each Cluster sold in >= 5 Countries.

I need to create separate ranks for the countries *by* clusters.
How do I tell my query to create these multiple ranks by clusters?

Here ist what I tried:

```sql
SELECT [Abfrage 10_Profit].[product 1]
     , [Abfrage 10_Profit].[product 2]
     , [Abfrage 10_Profit].[product 3]
     , [Abfrage 10_Profit].[Country]
     , [Abfrage 10_Profit].Profit
     , [Country] & [Profit] AS [CountryProfit]
     , (SELECT COUNT([Abfrage 10_Profit].[Country]) 
        FROM [Abfrage 10_Profit] as [CountryProfit]
        WHERE [Country] = [Abfrage 10_Profit].[Country] 
          AND Profit > [Abfrage 10_Profit].Profit)+1 AS Rank
FROM [Abfrage 10_Profit]
```

But the query doesn't go, it charges for forever.
Then I tried:

```sql
SELECT [Abfrage 10_Profit].[Product 1]
     , [Abfrage 10_Profit].[Product 2]
     , [Abfrage 10_Profit].[Product 3]
     , [Abfrage 10_Profit].[Country]
     , [Abfrage 10_Profit].Profit
     , (SELECT COUNT([Abfrage 10_Profit].[Country])
        FROM [Abfrage 10_Profit]
        WHERE [Abfrage 10_Profit].[Country] = [Abfrage 10_Profit].[Country] 
          AND [Abfrage 10_Profit].Profit >= [Abfrage 10_Profit].Profit) AS Rank 
FROM [Abfrage 10_Profit] 
ORDER BY [Abfrage 10_Profit].[Country] DESC;
```

By doing so I get 10604 in all the Rank lines (10604 = the numb of Tot Lines that I have) I am not able to get multiple Ranks within groups. How can I solve this?

Thank you very much!

[![Query Output][2]][2]

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far, along with sample that can be copied and pasted (i.e. not an image).

Comment: With:
SELECT [Abfrage 10_Profit].[Product 1], [Abfrage 10_Profit].[Product 2], [Abfrage 10_Profit].[Product 3], [Abfrage 10_Profit].[Country], [Abfrage 10_Profit].Profit, (SELECT COUNT([Abfrage 10_Profit].[Country]) FROM [Abfrage 10_Profit]
           WHERE [Abfrage 10_Profit].[Country] = [Abfrage 10_Profit].[Country] AND [Abfrage 10_Profit].Profit >= [Abfrage 10_Profit].Profit) AS Rank
FROM [Abfrage 10_Profit]
ORDER BY [Abfrage 10_Profit].[Country] DESC;

 I get 10604 in Rank (the numb of Tot Lines that I have) 
I am not able to get multiple Ranks within groups. How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Access SQL to do a grouped ranking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463116/use-access-sql-to-do-a-grouped-ranking)

Comment: Should edit question to show sample data as text table, not image and also the attempted SQL.

Comment: Unfortunately as new member, I cannot insert a Table, so I had to try to make it. and the SQL that I used is in the comment, but I can copy-paste it in the question.

Comment: Yes, please edit your post with all code and delete above SQL in comments. Also, you do not explain difference of two queries which use different columns. What does *charges for forever* mean?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `WHERE` conditions for each *cluster* in your correlated aggregate subquery. Also when using subqueries be sure to use table aliases to effectively differentiate between inner and outer queries that use same source (i.e., `[Abfrage 10_Profit]`).

```sql
SELECT ap.[Product 1]
     , ap.[Product 2]
     , ap.[Product 3]
     , ap.[Country]
     , ap.Profit
     , (SELECT COUNT(ap.[Country])
        FROM [Abfrage 10_Profit] sub_ap
        WHERE sub_ap.Profit >= ap.Profit
          AND sub_ap.[Product 1] = ap.[Product 1]
          AND sub_ap.[Product 2] = ap.[Product 2]
          AND sub_ap.[Product 3] = ap.[Product 3]
          AND sub_ap.[Country] = ap.[Country]) AS Rank 
FROM [Abfrage 10_Profit] ap
ORDER BY ap.[Country] DESC;
```

---

Also, correlated subqueries are a bit taxing on performance since query runs the `COUNT` aggregate for *every* row in outer query. If your table is very large with diversity of product clusters, processing may be long. Consider saving results in a temp table to avoid re-running each time you need rankings.

Also, for a very large table (tens to hundreds of thousands of rows) try breaking each of the five countries:

```sql
SELECT ap.[Product 1]
     , ap.[Product 2]
     , ap.[Product 3]
     , ap.[Country]
     , ap.Profit
     , (SELECT COUNT(ap.[Country])
        FROM [Abfrage 10_Profit] sub_ap
        WHERE sub_ap.Profit >= ap.Profit
          AND sub_ap.[Product 1] = ap.[Product 1]
          AND sub_ap.[Product 2] = ap.[Product 2]
          AND sub_ap.[Product 3] = ap.[Product 3]
          AND sub_ap.[Country] = 'Switzerland') AS Rank 
FROM [Abfrage 10_Profit] ap
WHERE ap.[Country] = 'Switzerland'
ORDER BY ap.[Country] DESC;
```

And stack them in a temporary table:

```sql
INSERT INTO RankTable ([Product 1], [Product 2], [Product 3], [Country], [Profit], [Rank])
SELECT [Product 1], [Product 2], [Product 3], [Country], [Profit], [Rank]
FROM mySwitzerlandQuery
```

```sql
INSERT INTO RankTable ([Product 1], [Product 2], [Product 3], [Country], [Profit], [Rank])
SELECT [Product 1], [Product 2], [Product 3], [Country], [Profit], [Rank]
FROM myGermanyQuery
```

```sql
INSERT INTO RankTable ([Product 1], [Product 2], [Product 3], [Country], [Profit], [Rank])
SELECT [Product 1], [Product 2], [Product 3], [Country], [Profit], [Rank]
FROM myAustriaQuery
```

```sql
...
```

Even break down by each combination of clusters (if combinations are at manageable sizes) which can even be automated by code (C#, Java, Python, PHP, R, VBA, etc.).

```sql
SELECT ap.[Product 1]
     , ap.[Product 2]
     , ap.[Product 3]
     , ap.[Country]
     , ap.Profit
     , (SELECT COUNT(ap.[Country])
        FROM [Abfrage 10_Profit] sub_ap
        WHERE sub_ap.Profit >= ap.Profit
          AND sub_ap.[Product 1] = 'Computer'
          AND sub_ap.[Product 2] = 'Keyboard'
          AND sub_ap.[Product 3] = 'Mouse'
          AND sub_ap.[Country] = 'Switzerland') AS Rank 
FROM [Abfrage 10_Profit] ap
WHERE ap.[Product 1] = 'Computer'
  AND ap.[Product 2] = 'Keyboard'
  AND ap.[Product 3] = 'Mouse'
  AND ap.[Country] = 'Switzerland'
ORDER BY ap.[Country] DESC;
```

Maybe one day soon, MS Access will have window functions to replace correlated subqueries like most other DBMS's as I advocated a few years ago for Access team to [Upgrade Access SQL dialect](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar). (Please vote!)